# Change value of second and following duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have 2 columns of data. As shown in the image below, first column has a list of duplicates and second column has the first day of the month as date. The first duplicate should be remained as 01-11-19, whereas the next duplicate should have 1 to be added in the cell to make it 02-11-19, followed by the other duplicates. How do I code this in VBA?

I tried this function, but it's not working as expected since it's modifying both the duplicates, but I only want the next duplicate to be modified.

```
Dim Rng, cel As range

Set Rng = .range(.Cells(firstrow, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 2))

For Each cel In Rng
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, cel.value) > 1 Then
        WorksheetName.Cells(cel.row, 2).value = WorksheetName.Cells(cel.row, 2).value + 1
    End If 
Next cel
```

Column 1 with duplicates and column 2 to be added 1 to make it next following date

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I have edited. Not sure if it helps..

Comment: Do you explicitly need this in vba? as it can be done with fomula as well.

Comment: @Bankar i would prefer VBA, but i can try with the formula as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here would be a formula approach, assume Column A is the duplicated data and column B the dates. Row one contains the headers and the required info is from row 2 onwards

```
First, sort the data, column B oldest to newest, then Column A smallest to largest

In cell C2, copy back the date from cell B2 (as this is the first data row, it will be the same date)

In cell C3, input the formula =IF(A2=A1,B2+1,B2), and copy it down to the final row of the raw data
```

You can script the same into vba, by recording the steps above and fine tuning where necessary